# How do I evaluate a TENS unit, having no experience with them?

Tags: pain, tens

A friend of mine has been recommended to use a [TENS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcutaneous_electrical_nerve_stimulation) unit for pain his nape (back of his neck) - and is going to purchase one. Neither of us has ever used such a device, and I've noticed there are numerous manufacturers of TENS units - none of which I am otherwise familiar with - sporting all sorts of features and parameters (number of programs, number of intensity settings, number and sizes of pads etc). There are also very large differences in prices between devices which I'm not able to explain to myself (e.g. device X has feature F and device Y doesn't so it makes sense X costs a lot more).

What I'd like help with is what criteria to apply when evaluating a potential TENS unit before choosing one to purchase. Even simple pitfalls or gotchas to look out for would help. After all, it's a device which electrocutes you a little...

Note: I am *not* asking for specific product recommendations.

Comment: I don't believe there can be a good answer to this question. First, to evaluate the quality of TENS units, one would need to review actual commercial products and then "recommend" one, wanted or not. Also, without knowing the person and the cause of his nap pain, you can't just suggest him TENS.

Comment: I have to agree with @Jan on this. What criteria to apply would depend on your friend's needs and that gets into medical advice, which is off topic here. Even if we avoid that pitfall, the end result is going to be largely a matter of opinion. This question can probably be salvaged, but to do so is going to require prior research on your part and construction of a question that can be answered with a firm, scientific answer rather than recommendations and opinions.

Comment: @CareyGregory Will asking about studies/references about evidence for TENS treatment of neck pain be on topic? What about asking also about the device brand and other treatment specific details such as modality, time, voltage, power, etc as used in the studies?

Comment: @TimurShtatland Sure, we've had previous questions about TENS and there's no problem with TENS questions as long as they fall within the guidelines of [What topics can I ask about here?](https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). I don't think we have any resident experts on the subject who can address details like voltage, power, etc, but you're free to ask and find out.